# Package bigmemory not installing on R 64 3.0.2

Tags: r, bigdata, package, r-bigmemory

I am trying to install the bigmemory package in R 64 version 3.0.2 on Windows. I get the following error:

> install.packages('bigmemory')

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Audrey/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message: package ‘bigmemory’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2) 

> library(bigmemory)

Error in library(bigmemory) : there is no package called ‘bigmemory’
```

Any help or insight will be much appreciated. I get the same error with previous R version 2.15.

Comment: For me this works: 
    install.packages(c("BH","biglm"))
    install.packages("bigmemory", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
    install.packages("bigmemory.sri", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
    install.packages("biganalytics", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
    install.packages("bigalgebra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
    library(bigmemory)

Comment: Or well this is a more recent version: 
    install.packages(c("BH","biglm")); library(devtools);
    devtools::install_github('kaneplusplus/bigmemory',local=T);
    library(bigmemory);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html under "Windows Binary". There are no windows binarys available. Have a look at the Read-Me file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the package's [news page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS), **"Windows support is temporarily suspended due to issues with the Boost headers"**. That's the latest entry on the page, dated 2013-03-09.

Comment: You need to change the version of R to 2.15.3